# higher-order (3+) Taylor expansion of a likelihood function

Tags: statistics, asymptotics, taylor-expansion, maximum-likelihood

I was wondering what is the effect if I replace the second derivative of the log-likelihood ("Likelihood" hereafter) function with its expectation in a higher-order Taylor expansion of the likelihood function.

Let the observations be i.i.d., $\ell(\theta)$ be the sample mean of individual likelihood over $N$ observations, and `l{r}(theta)` be the r-th derivative of `l(theta)` w.r.t. `theta`. A Taylor expansion of the likelihood around the truth (`theta_0`, scalar) and evaluated at the estimate (`theta_hat`, scalar) gives

`l(theta_hat) = l(theta_0) + l{1}(theta_0)(theta_hat-theta_0) + 1/2 l{2}(theta_0)(theta_hat-theta_0)^2 + ... + 1/k! l{k}(theta_0)(theta_hat-theta_0)^k + Op[N^(-k-1/2)]`.

$$
\ell(\hat\theta) = \ell(\theta_0) + \ell'(\theta_0)(\hat\theta-\theta_0) + \frac 1 2 \ell''(\theta_0)(\hat\theta - \theta_0)^2 + \cdots + \frac 1 {k!} \ell^{(k)}(\hat\theta - \theta_0)^k + O_p(N^{-k-1/2})
$$

If `k` were 2, we could `l{2}(theta_0)` with `E[l{2}(theta_0)]` with no problem. Now let `k>2` and I want the expansion to be correct in expectation. Can I still replace `l{2}(theta_0)` with `E[l{2}(theta_0)]`?

I understand that, typically,

$$
\ell^{(2)}(\theta_0) = E\left[ \ell^{(2)}(\theta_0) \right] + O_p(N^{-1/2})
$$

such that, in some applications, replacing `E[l{2}(theta_0)]` with `l{2}(theta_0)` will introduce a nonneglectable bias to the order of `Op(N^-1/2)`. But what is the effect, to what I want, of the replacement that I explained above?

I'm sorry that you are seeing this in such a bad format. I'm new to this place and they don't let me upload pictures....

Comment: @Michael, thank you for editing. I didn't know that I could actually put latex code in it.